# Motorola Defy Not Turning On

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-loop

I have tried to install a CyanogenMod on my Motorola Defy as illustrated [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1033654). The problem is that despite the phone had been rooted, I had some problems with ClockWorkMod and rebooted my phone in  recovery mode using the application that ships with the phone. I did remove the Cache and Factory settings and ran the zip file.

The problem is that upon restart, the phone kept rebooting itself, that is, I kept seeing the Motorola logo for a couple of minutes, and then, the phone reboots and the process is repeated.

Now, out of the blue, the phone is not even turning on. What I have is a small white light that turns on whenever I connect the phone to a laptop via usb. Any idea on how I can get the phone working? At the moment I do not really care about what OS version, as long as it runs.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: There seems to have been an issue with the battery, I have managed to load up the phone to recovery mode. Can anyone show me how can I install a fresh Operating System? I seem to only have access to the phone's boot up screen. Also, the laptop does not seem to be able to connect to the phone via usb.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have RSD Lite installed. Do a Google search and look for either 4.9 or above. Then you need to go to Motorola's site and install the drivers needed. Find an SBF file that will work for you, likely it will need to be a 2.2 file. Best thing to do is keep trying until you find one that works. Boot your phone in bootloader mode (volume up button) and if you get a message about a low battery you will need to find a way to charge up the phone. Go to the XDA developers forum and search for McGyver battery fix. (you can also find sbf files there) If RSD lite recognizes your phone flash the sbf file and let it do it's thing. More detailed instructions can be found on XDA as well, but that is the jist of what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

@npinti i also faced same issue, now i recovered from that.
i will give you the details how to recover from this situation.

**Steps:**

- It's a good thing you are able to run the `Zip` from the **Boot menu**, 
  First of all go to the [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1033654) and download the **Official jordan cyanogen build** (zip file/ Installation steps also given there).
- place the `Zip` file in **Memory card** and boot your mobile.
- Now go to

  Boot Menu--> Recovery --> Custom Recovery -->
     update/install from zip.
- Then select the `Zip` file and click on **Install/Update**.
- Then it will do **installation** of the `Zip` file and give the result as **completed**, then click on `Reboot System`.
- That's it! Now you will be able to Boot from new OS of `Cyanogen Mod`, it's Very nice to use..

  *if there is any problem you can contact the XDA forum or reply here.*

Comment: Hi azad, thanks very much for your response. I will try this as soon as I can. The last thing I tried to do was to install another copy of the OS using RSDLite, but at the end, when RSD is supposed to reboot the phone, the phone does not reboot. I am also having some issues accessing the boot menu.

Comment: Ok, Try with boot Menu & above procedure it will work.